# Creating a batch file using MSBuild to accomplish DB task

Tags: .net, sql-server, batch-file, msbuild

I am trying to create a batch file using MSBuild which will help me to accomplish the DB task of Table and Stored Procedure creation. Once they are created then there is a wait for ~60 seconds and the created Tables and Stored Procedures will be deleted. Time is variant here.

Below is the code I have written so far. I am unable to delete the created Tables and Stored Procedures from the batch file.

Batch file :

```
@echo off

msbuild /t:Build;Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath=<<file_name>>

echo Please wait ~60 seconds 
Timeout /t 60 /nobreak
echo Dropping tables and the Stored Procedures
```

After looking around the web. I was able to get the Database drop command but this is not I want to accomplish.

Any help/ tips is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi newbee. Can you explain a bit about the Why? Because using batch -> msbuild to create and remove tables/sprocs can't be the best way to accomplish these tasks. There are alternatives like Jobs in SQL server which you can schedule to perform certain tasks (creating tables/sprocs) at certain times.

Comment: @RalfdeKleine The purpose is to test certain scenarios using the batch file embedded in the code. I don't want to use the SQL Server to accomplish this task but want to execute it from the code.

Comment: Ok, so you wan't to roll back the SSDT publish you've run against a database?

Comment: Yes. Other reason for going this way is to automate the process. If there is any other better way to automate the process through code present then please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlPackage.exe to perform following actions (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin.)

1. Create a snapshot of target database

   sqlpackage /Action:Extract /SourceDatabaseName:"MyDatabase" /SourceServerName:localhost /TargetFile:"C:\SomeDirectory\Before.dacpac"
2. Build solution to create Dacpac

   msbuild .. your sln file
3. Perform publish using result step 2

   sqlpackage /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"C:\SomeDirectory\NewSchema.dacpac" /TargetDatabaseName:TestACM 
   /TargetServerName:".\sqlExpress"
4. Roll back republish using made snapshot in first step
   sqlpackage /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"C:\SomeDirectory\Before.dacpac" /TargetDatabaseName:TestACM 
   /TargetServerName:".\sqlExpress"

[SqlPackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: 1. Rollback is the best way. As there is no need to take the backup of the Database. 

2. No, there is no TFS Server available.